# wso2 how to run sample of pet store in wso2 mss1.0

Tags: wso2

There is a very complete sample of pet store in wso2 mss1.0. But there is no any document to introduce how to configure and run this sample in wso2 web site. Is there any document can help to deploy this demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use petstore in sample directory [1] and use Running as an MSA Application sample of WSO2 MSS. ./run.sh command will be used to test the sample. All the steps are explained the WSO2 MSS MSA Application Sample Documentation [2]

[1] https://github.com/wso2/product-mss/tree/master/samples/petstore

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/MSS100/Running+as+an+MSA+Application

Comment: What is the default port of  MSS? In document, it is said 8080. But when starting MSS, 8080 is not occupied.

Comment: It is 8080. I have checked on that and port 8080 is in Listening state when the MSS runs